# Search Feature in grid view, i have custom adapter, how to search using getfilter() in android

Tags: android, android-gridview, baseadapter

**DrawerAdapter.java**

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;

MainActivity.Pack[] pacsForAdapter;


public DrawerAdapter(Context c, MainActivity.Pack lists[]) {
    mContext = c;
    pacsForAdapter = lists;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pacsForAdapter.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView text;
    ImageView icon;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater li= (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.items, null); //items.xml contains a TextView and an ImageView
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
        viewHolder.icon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    viewHolder.text.setText(pacsForAdapter[position].label);
    viewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(pacsForAdapter[position].icon);

    return convertView;

    }
}
```

How can I add search feature, I've created an EditText mytext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchfield);

*I've searched for answers but, they seem a bit confusing, because I've used a class that holds few things like*

```
class Pack {
    Drawable icon;
    String label;
    String name;
}
```

**This class is in MainActivity.java**

*Something from MainActivity.java*

```
public void set_pacs() {
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> pacsList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
lists = new Pack[pacsList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < pacsList.size(); i++) {
lists[i] = new Pack();
lists[i].icon = pacsList.get(i).loadIcon(packageManager);
lists[i].name = pacsList.get(i).activityInfo.packageName;
lists[i].label = pacsList.get(i).loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
}
new SortApps().exchange_sort(lists);
drawerAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(this, lists);
mylist.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);
mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerClickListener(this, lists, packageManager));  //DrawerClickListener I'm using this to listen to clicks, i think it's another thing, not related to search.
}
```

I've studied some about **getFilter**, but confused, how that relates to the text, or **how to filter the items based on the label**.

I've spent like 2 days behind this, searching for solutions, but :(

*Please Help*

*Thanks.*

Comment: use `ArrayAdapter` it already implements `Filterable` interface

Comment: in place of BaseAdapter? and, then target what element(TextView or what, that is in ViewHolder class, what component i need to target to filter)

Comment: yes,  in place of BaseAdapter

Comment: and, what do i use to search for?  i mean, like using Filterable, i need to use that getFilter

Comment: yes,  you need to call getFilter().filter()

Comment: And what to do after extending ArrayAdapter, i guess, i need to create some ArrayList, can you please tell.... :)

Comment: Don't mind my stupidity(if there is), i'm new to these... so..

Comment: read ArrayAdapter docs

Comment: MainActivity.Pack[] pacsForAdapter;
   .... pacsForAdapter = lists;
class Pack {
    Drawable icon;
    String label;
    String name;
}       //this thing is hurting! can you please give some example, docs are not helpful. in my case. :(

Comment: The thing is, i don't have an ArrayList, How can i create one, as I am using a class's variables, MainActivity.Pack[] pacsForAdapter;

Comment: so you tried `ArrayAdapter<Pack> adapter;` and what went wrong?

Comment: Ooh, I didn't tried that, Arrayadapter<Pack> adapter> I'm going to try. Thanks.

Comment: Not helping, anyway, I'm gon find my way :) thanks anyway

Comment: did you call `getFilter().filter()`? did you override `Pack#toString`?

Comment: ArrayAdapter<Pack> adapter; not helping, as you can see code above this: drawerAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(this, lists);

Comment: you didnt answer my question...

Comment: Its confusing, for me... i did called getFilter().filter() and all, but, how can i override Pack#toString.. can you please explain.

Comment: Can you please give me a little example

Comment: return name + " " + label;

Comment: ArrayAdapter<Pack> adapter; this is going to be in Drawer, i'm confused, i think, is this going to be in setpacs()?

Comment: check [this](http://pastebin.com/Zp442kSm)